# PHP - How do I check if this WordPress Ninjaform shortcode is empty or not?

Tags: php, wordpress

Thanks for taking a look at my question.

What I need to do is pretty elementary, I'm using [Ninja Forms](https://ninjaforms.com/) to use as my form submission method. They have default post options which is great, so what this means is that I get any data via custom shortcodes, example:

If I want to get the name of a user it would be something like this:

```
[ninja_forms_field id=77]
```

What I'm trying to do is to add a conditional to a PHP code that will tell me if the shortcode is empty or not, something like this:

```
if([ninja_forms_field id=77]){
    echo "works";
} 
else{
    echo "nope";
}
```

Basic idea is to check if the shortcode is returning something, ive tried `!empty()` ... that doesn't work either.

[Here's a quick guide on using Shortcodes in Ninja Forms](http://docs.ninjaforms.com/customer/portal/articles/2042238-post-creation#post_creation_default_content)

If you have any ideas on how to check shortcodes in WordPress please let me know, thanks!!

Comment: Where are you using this code (it doesn't work like that in PHP, and an answer here will depend on where you are using your code)?

Comment: @Damien this PHP is used in the default post form, I installed a plugin called insert php... but regardless of this can you tell me a couple of possible solutions, I'll figure out where to go from there...

Thanks mate

Comment: I am not completely sure, but you need to use `do_shortcode()` function in a php file for **shortcodes**. So try to use `if(do_shortcode("[ninja_forms_field id=77]")){` or `if(!empty(do_shortcode("[ninja_forms_field id=77]"))){`. Let us know if it works…